# Why my gpio input changes the internal resistance when running the python code?

Tags: gpio, voltage

I have a raspberry pi receiving inputs with a 300k resistance connected between the voltage input (12V)  and the gpio. When my python code is not running the voltage at the gpio is 1.7v, but when I run my code the voltage goes up to 5.4v. I tried to add another 300k resistor to see if I could lower the voltage at the gpio, but the voltage just dropped down to 5.2v. The pi still runs perfectly when receiving this amount of voltage. I want to understand why the circuit is behaving this way. I also tried using a 900k resistance before the gpio input and the voltage is still 5.1-5.2v at the gpio.

Comment: the observed behaviour is most likely the result of your code

Comment: You'll probably need to post code and maybe a photo of the wiring to get help on this.

Comment: Most likely because you instructed your code to change pin resistance.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a resistor in series will not drop the voltage.  It will simply reduce the current.

Fortunately you seem to have limited the current to a level which the Pi's GPIO protection circuitry can handle.  **However you are risking destroying the Pi when you connect any voltage more than 3V3 to a GPIO**.

One way to produce a safe voltage for the Pi GPIO is to use a [resistor divider circuit](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/voltage-divider-calculator/).